# PowerBI extracting JSON record to a custom column

Tags: json, powerbi

I am taking data from a web source and have expanded all my columns. When everything is split and expanded, my columns look like:

```
result.col1| result.col2| result.col3| result.col4
val1       | val2       | Record     |val4
```

In here we can see that result.col3 has another JSON record.

What I am trying to accomplish is: How can I create a custom column that reads each Record and outputs a value based off one of the items?

For example the JSON record has:

```
link: https://google.com
value: 444333
```

I want the custom column's row to display "A" if value inside the record is "444333"

Comment: please consider accepting answers if they answer your question

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the `result.col3` column, expand the copy, build your custom column based on the expanded fields, then delete them.